# Rescaling weights after drop connect

Tags: neural-networks, dropconnect

From what I understand, you're supposed to rescale your activation layer after an application of dropout by an amount proportional to how much you dropped.  Essentially truing up the lost relevance (poorly stated, but I hope I made myself clear).  My question is whether this rescaling for lost weight is necessary or recommended after an application of drop connect on a matrix of weights?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike dropout, the inference of dropconnect is sort of a MC method according to the [papper](http://www.matthewzeiler.com/pubs/icml2013/icml2013.pdf) Sec 3.2.
[image][image]
It approximates the pre-activation values with Gaussian distributions, draws a number of samples from the Gaussians, and take the average of the activation values of the samples.